# How can I add information to file that uploaded with plupload library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```js
$('.plupload').pluploadQueue({
  runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,browserplus',
  url: '/uploads/upload?_id=' + $('#fax_id').val(),
  max_file_size: '100mb',
  chunk_size: '1mb',
  sortable: true,
  filters: [{
      title: "Image File",
      extensions: "jpg,gif,png,jpeg,tiff,tif,bmp"
    },
    {
      title: "Document File",
      extensions: "pdf,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,doc,docx,txt,rtf"
    }
  ],
  flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
  silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
  init: {
    FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {},
    Error: function(up, args) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I wanted to upload a file with using plupload library. And also some text must be added to the uploaded file. Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain more. Just want to send text data? or else add it to the file itself?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to send specific data to uploaded file like var data = 'This is a text'; And this text isn't dinamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `multipart_params` to pass additional fields along with each upload request.

```
$('.plupload').pluploadQueue({
  ...
  multipart_params: {
    data: 'This is a text'
  }
});
```

**More Info:**
https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Options#multipart
https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Options#multipart_params